# Hiding ID value in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-autocomplete

my php script handling the mysql request and array is

```
mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_login, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database);

$req = "SELECT ID, name, date, page_id "
        ."FROM alltickets "
        ."WHERE ID LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' OR name LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' OR date LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' OR page_id LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%'   ";

$query = mysql_query($req);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
        $results[] = array('label' => $row['ID'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['date'] . ' ' . $row['page_id']);
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

my jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#texfield').autocomplete({
    source: 'autocomp.php',
    minChars: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#texfield').val(ui.item.name);
        $('#brandid').val(ui.item.page_id)
    },
    search: function() {
        $('#brandid').val('');
    } });
});
```

I am trying to get "page_id" not to be visible in "texfield"(which is the input text field for the query result) but instead to be passed to "brandid" (which is an hidden input field)

the above is all working except "page_id" is being displayed in "texfield" and not being posted to "brandid" what so ever.

I am guessing its to do with the array, thanks for your help

Comment: Note that the mysql_ extension is deprecated http://www.webmaster-source.com/2011/07/25/php-to-deprecate-mysql-extension-in-favor-of-mysqli-and-pdo/ it is highly advisable to adopt mysqli or pdo extensions

Comment: Urgh... another question with code containing `mysql_*`.